# Vertical Slice Architecture Feature Dependency

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I am using clean architecture and DDD less than one year and currently looking to vertical slice architecture to organize my code better but I have an important question here:

If I have features like this

- getCart
- getProfileInfo
- getShippingAddress
- getPaymentMethod

And now I need to implement a new feature called `placeOrder` and this feature depends on some other features like `getCart`, `getProfileInfo`, `getShippingAddresss`, `getPaymentMethod`, what should I do in that case, can I inject other features in `placeOrder` service, or should I duplicate the code in this feature to be self-contained?

Answer (score 1):

The main idea would be *not* to have slices (use-cases) depending on other use-cases. I am not an expert, and [this is my (perhaps biased opinion)](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/uncle-bob-weve-failed-you-7a988971c0e8?sk=2edb77f26790e43c65ed04eb0e0d3942).  In order to keep the use cases decoupled, I usually used one of the following 2 approaches:

Firstly, you can have some common components as long as they stay use-case agnostic. In other words, you can reuse the database gateway (or repositories), some domain entities...etc as long as they do not include use-case-specific business logic. This also means you cannot reuse a use case itself or a component that is very specific to one particular use case.

Let's simplify a bit the question and only consider the `view cart` and `place order` use cases/slices:

[image]
As you can see, we are reusing entity and repository, but not the `use case` class itself, nor its incoming or outgoing request/response models/dtos.

You can read [this article of hgraca](https://herbertograca.com/2017/11/16/explicit-architecture-01-ddd-hexagonal-onion-clean-cqrs-how-i-put-it-all-together/?fbclid=IwAR3TINiITpDWBU2YL4c3c01YJNCJIGEz3kaMmiwu6EzQRou6D3iZuLnS8Ts) to dive deeper into the concept, especially the section about *Data storage shared between components*.

---

Secondly, as you mentioned, you try to completely decouple the `cart`, `profile`, and `order` "slices". One way of achieving this would be through some application-internal `domain events`.

For example, let's say that whenever an `order` is placed, something about the `profile` module/slice needs to be updated. In this case, the `profile` module can listen to orders being placed and react accordingly.

Finally, keep in mind that there will always be trade-offs to make. In this case, it's about duplication vs coupling. As you suggested, you can duplicate some lines to avoid coupling, or you can reuse some components, but this will create some indirect coupling (different use cases will depend on the common/shared component). In the end, it's always a matter of comparing the pros and cons of each solution and see what better applies to your context.

Comment: thanks for this valuable answer, lemme explain my use case a little, what I understand is domain events are used to notify other entities about data updates but what I am taking about is getting data, as I mentioned, if I have use case called `getCart` this use case returns the cart to and API, and I have another usecase called `placeOrder`, this use case needs to read the cart also to get the items, in this case should I duplicate it in placeOrder use case or depend on another feature?

Comment: please note that I am using BFF pattern, so basically here is no connection to a db but I am executing actions across multiple services and I wanted to build that BFF based on vertical slice architecture, not sure if this is a good choice or not

Comment: I would use the same diagram/idea, but, instead of DB gateway, there will be a backend API